# Display Clickable links in Google Doc Html query output

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am creating a Spreadsheet to hold a List of URLs, I have created a Query URL to filter the list and display the correct links in an html format, but I need the links to be clickable in the page

The URL is below
https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=Select%20B%20WHERE%20A%20LIKE%20%22Abigail%22&key=1MDAiwcP-OYj52Va0vkcNN5cMTg2KSb7cyqLbg3GrblA

I have tried adding the Hyperlink html tags in the query and in the source data but neither have helped (in query generated error, in source just displayed in text as part of the result), I am able to click the link when I access with preview tag so the link is configured correctly:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MDAiwcP-OYj52Va0vkcNN5cMTg2KSb7cyqLbg3GrblA/preview#gid=0

Comment: This is not possible natively, since the ````QUERY```` function used in the URL cannot output hyperlinks, only string values. You have to build your HTML manually using script.

Comment: OK as an alternate solution I can separate the data in to tabs so I don't need the Query, But I would like to be able to link to a preview of the sheet that goes directly to the correct tab using the gid, I know how to do this in Edit mode but have not been able to do it in preview display

Comment: The URL changes when you click on the tab on the preview, specifically the gid. If you use that URL you will go directly to that tab.